# Trouble installing homebrew on New Mac

Tags: macos, terminal, homebrew

Once I install homebrew on my terminal it works. But when I close the terminal and reopen to use brew, it cannot find the command.

On reopening the terminal it says:

```
/Users/abc/.zshrc:export:2: not valid in this context: Support/JetBrains/Toolbox/scriptseval:/opt/homebrew/bin:/opt/homebrew/bin
```

This is what my .zprofile looks like after installing homebrew using the official docs:

```
# Added by Toolbox App
export PATH="$PATH:/Users/anshgupta/Library/Application Support/JetBrains/Toolbox/scripts"
eval "$(/opt/homebrew/bin/brew shellenv)"
```

Please explain why does it not recognise that I have installed it and how can I fix this

Answer (score 3):

OnTerminal,

```
  ~ % git clone https://github.com/Homebrew/brew homebrew        
    
  ~ % eval "$(homebrew/bin/brew shellenv)"
    
  ~ % brew update --force --quiet

  ~ brew update
    Already up-to-date.
```

Here brew installation documentation link - https://docs.brew.sh/Installation

Answer (score 2):

Try putting the line `eval "$(/opt/homebrew/bin/brew shellenv)"` to the top of the file, save it and restart your terminal.